# jquery how to get html of image in nested div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html

```
  <a class="lid" id="1"> 
     <div class="map_image">
      <img width="220" height="145" alt="" src="photo.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
     </div>
  </a>
```

Im using the following jquery to get the id of a link.

```
  function onlid {
   .setContent($(this).attr("id"));
  }

  $('.lid').on('mouseover', onlid);
```

so in this case content is set to 1, as the id of a class lid is 1.

what I would like is to get the whole html of  and set it after 1.

So content would be

```
   1 <img width="220" height="145" alt="" src="photo.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
```

Im trying something like

```
      .setContent($(this).attr("id") + $(this.map_image).html());
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you copy that function onlid correctly? that would throw an error

Comment: Not a good idea to have Div inside A tag.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do with the HTML.

This code should find the HTML inside of your `map_image` class relative to that anchor tag and alert it:

```
function onlid (event) {
   var $lid = $(event.target);
   var imgHTML = $lid.find('.map_image')[0].innerHTML;
   var lidId = $lid.attr('id');
   alert(lidId + imgHTML);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,   var imgHTML = $lid.find('.map_image')[0].innerHTML; helped i just changed $lid to $(this).